# Send Data from Drupal to node.js

Tags: php, node.js, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-form-submission

I'm a newbie with drupal.

I was trying to send data from drupal to node.js function and save the data from node into mongo.

I wrote a function in php

```
function sample_working_submit($form, &$form_state) { //Function to connect with node and save into Mongo using node
  $Name = check_plain($form_state['values']['Name']);
  $Age = check_plain($form_state['values']['Age']);
  $request_url = "http://10.20.5.112:3001/save/$Name/$Age ";
  $response = drupal_http_request($request_url);
}
```

This is working as long as there is no 'space' between the names(input). How can save the input with spaces.Why does this issue came?

How can i rewrite the function as post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$url = http://localhost:8080/myservlet;

$data = array (
    'name' => check_plain($form_state['values']['Name']),
    'age' => check_plain($form_state['values']['Age'])
    );

$response = drupal_http_request($url, $headers, 'POST', json_encode($data));
?>
```

This would POST data to URL. Note that you need to change logic in server side as well to receive POST data instead of GET data.

[Refer here](https://drupal.org/node/221136) for more info

Comment: I was trying this but I'm getting error Warning: http_build_query(): Parameter 1 expected to be Array or Object. I included $headers = array();

Comment: $options = array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'data' => $jsonData,
                'timeout' => 15,
                'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
        );


 $result = drupal_http_request($request_url, $options);

Answer (score 1):

If the space between the names is the issue, try using [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)().

The code will be something like:

```
$Name = urlencode(check_plain($form_state['values']['Name']));
```

Comment: But in this case its saved in the database with a '+'. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Where does the `+` come from ?!

Comment: @MuhammadReda Node.js application logic most probably. Sreekesh, you're going to need to alter this on the Node.js side of things.

Comment: When I input name as 'sreekesh okky' its send to the node as 'sreekesh+okky'

Comment: @SreekeshOkky Perhaps then you should splitup the parameters, or stil better use JSON, instead of relying on GET.

Comment: @2-Stroker I tried that. But i got confused in how to send JSON. Can you help me out with a sample.

Answer (score 0):

For POST requests I use [SimpleBrowser](http://www.simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html) instead of drupal_http_request(). It's easy to use and you'll be able to pass strings in any form.